# Не происходит вертикальное выравнивание

Tags: html, css

Нужно отцентровать статичную страницу по горизонтали и вертикали, но почему-то у меня вертикальное выравнивание не происходит. Я что-то сделал не так?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="plain-text">Vintage</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.wrapper .container .holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.plain-text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте к стилям:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Рабочий пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/8h6qnnnc/)